Toggling between elements - Javascript - Digital Audio Workstation
I'm currently working on coding a digital audio workstation however I'm encountering an issue with my elements. I'm trying to implement a function in which if on a row, a dropzone is playing an audio, clicking on another dropzone of that same row would simultaneously stop playing the other dropzone and start playing the one I just clicked on. However what I am encountering is that I have to click two times on a dropzone for it to play (one time to stop/pause the other dropzone and one time to start playing the dropzone) which I do not get why
Please find my code below and thank you so much in advance for all the answers and help!


const dropzones = document.getElementsByClassName("loop-cell");
const rowPlayingAudio = {};

Array.from(dropzones).forEach((dropzone, index) => {
  let audio = null;
  let isPlaying = false;

  dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropzone.style.borderColor = "blue";
  });

  dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
    if (!audio) {
      dropzone.style.borderColor = "#fda0d3";
    } else {
      dropzone.style.borderColor = "#a2d0f1";
    }
  });

  dropzone.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropzone.style.borderColor = "#a2d0f1";

    const files = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.files).filter((file) =>
      file.type.includes("audio/")
    );

    files.forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        const audioSrc = e.target.result;
        audio = new Audio(audioSrc);
        audio.loop = true;
        isPlaying = false;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  });

  dropzone.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (audio) {
      const rowIndex = Math.floor(index / 8);

      if (
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex] &&
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex].audio !== audio
      ) {
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex].audio.pause();
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex].audio.currentTime = 0;
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex].isPlaying = false;
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex] = null;
      }

      if (isPlaying) {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        isPlaying = false;
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex] = null;
      } else {
        audio.play();
        isPlaying = true;
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex] = {
          audio,
          dropzone,
          isPlaying,
          index
        };
      }

      audio.onended = () => {
        setLaunchpadLight(index, 0);
        isPlaying = false;
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex] = null;
      };
    }
  });
});
.loop-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  gap: 7px;
}

.loop-cell {
  background: #fec9e6;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid #fda0d3;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>LaunchPad 2 Looper</h1>
  <main>
    <div class="loop-grid">
      <div id="dropzone0" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone1" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone2" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone3" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone4" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone5" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone6" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone7" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
      <div id="dropzone8" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
      <div id="dropzone9" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
      <div id="dropzone10" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
      <div id="dropzone11" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
      <div id="dropzone12" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
      <div id="dropzone13" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
      <div id="dropzone14" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
      <div id="dropzone15" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>



I tried deleting any potential duplicates but I don't get where the issue could be coming from

please create a [mre]

cut the code shorter, if that's what you meant, sorry i dont use stack overflow that much

Thank you. Actually I meant the part of reproducible example. Because it's not easy to see the issue without executing the code.

Oh, I made a singular runnable code (in html including minimal style and script) that I'm putting in the edit that should show that upon dragging and dropping audios on multiple dropzones on a same row, toggling between the dropzones by clicking on a first will seemingly work but wanting to do it again causes to have to click two times for it to work

Great Minimal Reproducible Example.
I fixed the issue. Changes made:

Handling state of play (rowPlayingAudio) using the built in events play, ended, pause. I am even toggling a class playing on the playing element.
I am attaching those events soon after creation of audio
Now the click handler is much simpler, knowing status will be handled using the events.



const dropzones = document.querySelectorAll(".loop-cell");
const rowPlayingAudio = {};

function setLaunchpadLight() {
  // dummy
}

Array.from(dropzones).forEach((dropzone, index) => {
  let audio = null;
  let isPlaying = false;
  const rowIndex = Math.floor(index / 8);

  dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropzone.style.borderColor = "blue";
  });

  dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
    if (!audio) {
      dropzone.style.borderColor = "#fda0d3";
    } else {
      dropzone.style.borderColor = "#a2d0f1";
    }
  });

  dropzone.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropzone.style.borderColor = "#a2d0f1";

    const files = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.files).filter((file) =>
      file.type.includes("audio/")
    );

    files.forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        const audioSrc = e.target.result;
        audio = new Audio(audioSrc);
        audio.loop = true;
        isPlaying = false;

        function onStopForAnyReason(ev) {
          dropzone.classList.remove("playing")
          setLaunchpadLight(index, 0);
          isPlaying = false;
          audio.currentTime = 0;
          delete rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex];
        }

        audio.onended = onStopForAnyReason
        audio.onpause = onStopForAnyReason
        audio.onplay = () => {
          dropzone.classList.add("playing")
          isPlaying = true;
          rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex] = {
            audio,
            dropzone,
            isPlaying,
            index
          };
        }
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  });

  dropzone.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (audio) {

      if (rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex]) {
        rowPlayingAudio[rowIndex].audio.pause();
      }

      if (isPlaying) {
        audio.pause();
      } else {
        audio.play();
      }
      isPlaying = !isPlaying

    }
  });
});
.loop-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  gap: 7px;
}

.loop-cell {
  background: #fec9e6;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid #fda0d3;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}

.loop-cell.playing {
  background: green;
}
<h1>LaunchPad 2 Looper</h1>
<main>
  <div class="loop-grid">
    <div id="dropzone0" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone1" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone2" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone3" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone4" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone5" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone6" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone7" class="loop-cell">Keys</div>
    <div id="dropzone8" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    <div id="dropzone9" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    <div id="dropzone10" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    <div id="dropzone11" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    <div id="dropzone12" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    <div id="dropzone13" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    <div id="dropzone14" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
    <div id="dropzone15" class="loop-cell">Bass</div>
  </div>
</main>




My issue has been fixed,it now works! Thank you so much!
